# Moving (large amounts of) data between environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a Rails 3 app - it's an interface to research about various projects. We don't want researchers accidentally putting duff data into the user site, so we have separated the application off using a `dataentry` environment, used by the researchers, and a `production` environment, which is user-facing. Researchers put new data into the `dataentry` database, which is checked and then signed off by an editor; the data stretches over 30 models, which have various `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations.

What I'd like to do is work out how to periodically move the data from the data entry environment to the live environment. I don't really want to trash the `production` database and dump `dataentry` into it each time, because I don't want to lose e.g. subscriptions from new users signed up on the live site.

Most of the solutions I've seen for migrating data between environments either involve a) dumping things out to YAML or similar, or b) loading whole tables into a Ruby array, switching database connection, and doing an `each` loop on the array to load them back in. Both approaches seem suboptimal when the tables are very large.

I could (conceivably) `mysqldump` all the relevant tables from `dataentry` and pipe the result into `mysql production` but it seems a bit like a blunt instrument.

Are there any best practices for managing this kind of "data staging" in Rails?

Comment: have a look at http://www.rubyrep.org/

Comment: What about replicating the data from data entry to production with a filter on the replication?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731599/can-i-set-up-a-filtered-star-pattern-database-replication  That way it's always ready and you don't have to sync in bulk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what I went with in the end was [`pt-table-sync`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html) in a cron job.